# uploadify - limit to single file upload

Tags: javascript, uploadify

Is there a way to limit the upload to 1 file in uploadify?

I can't see anything in the docs? I have the max file size bit sorted but can't find a way to limit it to only allow one file selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting "multi" to false.

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/multi/

Answer (score 0):

Set multi to false as Salman said,
but also set "uploadLimit" to 1.

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/uploadlimit/

"multi" will keep users from upload more than one file at a time, but they'll keep being able to upload several files (a single file at a time). With uploadLimit:1, you also keep them from adding more file in multiple uploads.